# convert python to c programming

Tags: python, c

I need help converting a few lines of code from python to C

this is python code:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[11,11],[1,1])
def queryData(D, P, Radius):
     Neighbors = []
for Pn in range(0, len(Data)):
    if np.linalg.norm(D[P]-Data[Pn])<Radius:
        Neighbors.append(Pn)
return tetangga
print(queryData(X,1,2))
```

and this is C code that I was make:

```
int *queryData(int Titik, float Radius, int *sz){
    int Neighbors=(int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i<ndata; i++){
        Tetangga1[i] = 0;
    }

    float jarak[ndata];
    int deltaX[ndata];
    int deltaY[ndata];
    int size = 0;
    for(int Pn=0; Pn<ndata; Pn++){
        deltaX[Pn] = (datainput_x[Titik] - datainput_x[Pn])*(datainput_x[Titik] - datainput_x[Pn]);
        deltaY[Pn] = (datainput_y[Titik] - datainput_y[Pn])*(datainput_y[Titik] - datainput_y[Pn]);
        jarak[Pn]  = sqrt(deltaX[Pn] + deltaY[Pn]);
        if(jarak[Pn]<Radius){
            Neighbors[Pn] = Pn;     
        }
    }
    return Tetangga;
}
```

first I have problem how to make list on C such as in python
second I think that about I make wrong about return pointer

please help me and sorry about my english

Comment: in your function parameters you use `sz` (which I guess is for size) yet in allocating `Neighbors` you use `size` which I cannot see defined in your code

Comment: also if you are using global variables please show them in your C code

Comment: And the indentation of your python code does not seems to be correct

Comment: There seems to be missing pieces in your python code that make it more difficult to understand and make it impossible to help you in a meaningful way

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed all your compiler errors. Hopefully this will help you get what you need. The main issue with your code is dereferencing sz. You need to use *sz to get the value you want

```
int *queryData(int Titik, float Radius, int *sz){
    int Tetangga1[*sz];
    int ndata = *sz;
    int datainput_x[*sz];
    int datainput_y[*sz];
    int* Neighbors=(int*)malloc(*sz*sizeof(int));
    
    for(int i=0; i<ndata; i++){
        Tetangga1[i] = 0;
    }

    float jarak[ndata];
    int deltaX[ndata];
    int deltaY[ndata];
    int size = 0;
    for(int Pn=0; Pn<ndata; Pn++){
        deltaX[Pn] = (datainput_x[Titik] - datainput_x[Pn])*(datainput_x[Titik] - datainput_x[Pn]);
        deltaY[Pn] = (datainput_y[Titik] - datainput_y[Pn])*(datainput_y[Titik] - datainput_y[Pn]);
        jarak[Pn]  = sqrt(deltaX[Pn] + deltaY[Pn]);
        if(jarak[Pn]<Radius){
            Neighbors[Pn] = Pn;     
        }
    }
    return Tetangga1;
}
```

Comment: For future note, see the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) -- questions that aren't sufficiently well-formed to be a good knowledgebase entry are generally best guided into that form (only one -- unique -- problem, very clear and specific about what it is, with a title that clearly describes it so other people with the same issue can easily find it) before being answered.

Comment: To put it a little differently: Our primary goal should be to help not the person who first asks a question, but all the future people with the same problem (who a good question/answer pair will help by virtue of coming up in search). Providing assistance that's only helpful to the person who asked the question, rather than insisting that they break their problem down to something other people can learn from, shortchanges those future readers.

Comment: there is something that tells me that the returning a stack allocated VLA might not be working as advertised